# Dock icon started to blink

Tags: 22.04

I do not understand why the icon suddenly started to blink.

App: x2goclient

Ubuntu: 22.04

[image: Ubuntu icon blinks]

Tried to refresh icon cache.

Not sure what else to do.

The icon blinks once every minute or so.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned: Allways check for the latest change made. I installed the AppImageLauncher lite, instead of the full version.

https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases

Obviously made the icon flicker..

Uninstalled the lite and installed the full. Problem solved.